# Associativity of Product Sigma Algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

\begin{align}
  Let (X,\mathscr{A}, \mu), (Y,\mathscr{B},\nu) ,\space and\space (Z,\mathscr{C},\theta)\space be\space measure\space spaces.\space Show\space that\space \mathscr{A}\times\mathscr{B}\times\mathscr{C}=(\mathscr{A}\times\mathscr{B})\times\mathscr{C}=\mathscr{A}\times(\mathscr{B}\times\mathscr{C}).
\end{align}
I have been working on this exercise for some time and haven't been making any progress. I tried letting
\begin{align}
  \mathscr{E}=\mathscr{A}\times\mathscr{B}
\end{align}
and working with
\begin{align}
  \mathscr{E}\times\mathscr{C}
\end{align}
But I'm at a loss. I managed to find a text located here http://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/measure-book1.pdf that features the problem as exercise 1.7.21 but provides no solution. I could really use some more help though. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the product $\sigma$-algebra of two Measure Spaces $(\Omega_{1},\mathfrak{F}_{1},\mu_{1})$ and $(\Omega_{2},\mathfrak{F}_{2},\mu_{2})$is defined as $$\mathfrak{F}_{1} \otimes \mathfrak{F}_{2} = \sigma(\{A_1 \times A_2 |A_1\in \mathfrak{F}_{1}, A_2 \in \mathfrak{F}_{2})\}$$ So the way I would do it is define your $A\times B$ as another $\sigma$-algebra, say $P$ (whatever) and use this definition, then do the same for $B\times C$.

Comment: Ok, so if I say that E_1=\sigma({A \times B |A\in\mathscr{A}, B\in\mathscr{B}}) and look at E_1\times C, can I just say that A\times B\times C is really the same as (A\times B)\times C?

Comment: I don't understand your writing, just try to visualize it as a 3 axis problem, x,y and z, they all form sigma algebras so their products are associative and again form a product-sigma-algebra

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that I managed to put together.

\begin{align}
 \forall A\times B\times C\space with\space A\in\mathscr{A},\space B\in \mathscr{B}, \space and\space C\in \mathscr{C}\space we\space have\space that\newline
 \ A\times B\in \mathscr{A} \times \mathscr{B} \implies A\times B\times C\in (\mathscr{A} \times \mathscr{B})\times \mathscr{C}\newline
\ Similarly,\space A\times B\times C\in \mathscr{A}\times(\mathscr{B}\times \mathscr{C})\newline
\implies \mathscr{A}\times \mathscr{B}\times \mathscr{C}\subset(\mathscr{A}\times\mathscr{B})\times\mathscr{C}, \space\space\space\mathscr{A}\times \mathscr{B}\times \mathscr{C}\subset\mathscr{A}\times(\mathscr{B}\times\mathscr{C})\newline\newline So\space it\space suffices\space to\space show\space that\space the\space reverse\space inclusion\space is\space also\space true\newline\newline
\ Let B'=\{E\in(\mathscr{A}\times\mathscr{B})\times C:E\in\mathscr{A}\times\mathscr{B}\times\mathscr{C}\}.\newline
\ Then\space B'\space is\space a\space \sigma algebra\space by\space definition.\space Fix\space C.\space Then\space F\times C\in\mathscr{A}\times\mathscr{B}\times\mathscr{C}.\space Thus,\space the\space generating\ sets\ of\ (\mathscr{A}\times\mathscr{B})\times\mathscr{C}\space lie\ in\ \mathscr{A}\times\mathscr{B}\times\mathscr{C}.\newline But\ (\mathscr{A}\times\mathscr{B})\times\mathscr{C}\ is\ the\ least\ \sigma algebra\ containing\ those\ generating\ sets.\newline \implies\mathscr{A}\times\mathscr{B}\times\mathscr{C}\subset(\mathscr{A}\times\mathscr{B})\times\mathscr{C}.\newline A\ similar\ argument\ provides\ the\ third\ equality.\square
\end{align}

Comment: I don't think this proves the claim. In particular, your definition of $B'$ seems errorneous (plus, you don't use it after "showing" that it is a σ-algebra), $F$ is not defined, the statement about the generating sets is not obvious and the last inequality / subset relation should probably be the other way around.

Comment: In case someone else is looking for a proof: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1423219/27879