# Associativity of product measures

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose we have measure spaces $(X_i, M_i, \mu_i), i=1, 2,3$, that are complete and $\sigma$-finite. I learned how to form a product measure from two measure spaces, but I wasn't so sure about product of more than two. So I am learning about it at the moment. I was wondering how does one show that
$$
\mu_1 \times (\mu_2 \times \mu_3) = (\mu_1 \times \mu_2) \times \mu_3.
$$
Any hint/solution is appreciated. Thank you!

PS I was also wondering about
$$
M_1 \times (M_2 \times M_3) = (M_1 \times M_2) \times M_3.
$$

Comment: Say $\mu$ is one of those triple products and $E=E_1\times E_2\times E_3$, where $E_j\in M_j$. What is $\mu(E)$?

Comment: It should be $\mu(E) = \mu_1(E_1) \cdot \mu_2(E_2) \cdot \mu_3(E_3)$ in either case I think!

Comment: Yes. Now you say the measures are sigma-finite. First consider the case when they're finite. Say $A$ is the set of finite unions of sets of the form $E_1\times E_2\times E_3$. Then $A$ is an algebra that generates the sigma-algebra of measurable functions. Recall the Monotone Class Theorem...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the following I will prove that the product of three measures is associative. This can easily be generalized to a finite number of measures and possibly to countably many measures. As the OP indicates in his/her post scriptum, it all boils down to proving the associativity result for the $\sigma$-algebras involved.

---

Let $(X_i,\Sigma_i, \mu_i)$ be a measure space, $i = 1,\ 2,\ 3$. In the following I will use the (standard) notations $$\Sigma_i \times \Sigma_j = \{A \times B : A \in \Sigma_i,\ B \in \Sigma_j\}$$ $$\Sigma_i \otimes \Sigma_j = \sigma\big(\Sigma_i \times \Sigma_j\big),$$ where $\sigma(\cdot)$ indicates the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the argument, i.e. the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains the argument. We can finally state the result we want to prove

> **CLAIM**: $\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2 \otimes \Sigma_3 := \sigma(\Sigma_1 \times \Sigma_2 \times \Sigma_3) = \sigma((\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2) \times \Sigma_3) = \sigma(\Sigma_1 \times (\Sigma_2 \otimes \Sigma_3)).$

*Synopsis of the proof:* $\Sigma_i \times \Sigma_j \subset \Sigma_i \otimes \Sigma_j$ is a [$\pi$-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_system). Define the "good set" and apply the [$\pi-\Lambda$-system Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_system#The_.CF.80-.CE.BB_Theorem). Then use the minimality of $\sigma(\cdot)$ several times.

**PROOF:** Notice that $$(\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2) \times \Sigma_3 = \{A \times B : A \in \Sigma_1\otimes\Sigma_2,\ B \in \Sigma_3\},$$
then fix $B \in \Sigma_3$ and let $$\Lambda = \{A : A \in \Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2,\ A \times B \in \sigma(\Sigma_1 \times \Sigma_2 \times \Sigma_3)\}.$$

Clearly $\Sigma_1 \times \Sigma_2 \subset \Lambda$. Let's prove that $\Lambda$ is a $\Lambda$-system.

- $X_1 \times X_2 \times B \in \Sigma_1 \times \Sigma_2 \times \Sigma_3$ then $X_1 \times X_2 \in \Lambda$.
- Let $A_1,A_2 \in \Lambda$, $A_1 \subset A_2$. We need to show that $A_2 \setminus A_1 \in \Lambda$, i.e. we need to show that $(A_2 \setminus A_1) \times B \in \sigma(\Sigma_1 \times \Sigma_2 \times \Sigma_3)$. This is easy since $\sigma(\Sigma_1 \times \Sigma_2 \times \Sigma_3)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, indeed $$(A_2 \setminus A_1) \times B = (A_2 \times B) \setminus (A_1 \times B) = (A_2 \times B) \cap (A_1 \times B)^c \in \sigma(\Sigma_1 \times \Sigma_2 \times \Sigma_3).$$
- Let $\{A_i\}$ be an increasing sequence of sets in $\Lambda$. We need to show that $\cup A_i \in \Lambda$. As before, this easily follows from the fact that $\sigma(\Sigma_1 \times \Sigma_2 \times \Sigma_3)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Let's write out the details! $$\Big(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\Big) \times B = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}(A_i \times B) \in \sigma(\Sigma_1 \times \Sigma_2 \times \Sigma_3).$$

We can finally apply the $\pi-\Lambda$-system Theorem to conclude that $\sigma (\Sigma_1 \times \Sigma_2) \subset \Lambda$ and hence $\sigma(\Sigma_1 \times \Sigma_2) \times B \subset \sigma(\Sigma_1 \times \Sigma_2 \times \Sigma_3).$
Since this is true for every $B \in \Sigma_3$ we obviously get that $$(\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2) \times \Sigma_3 \subset \sigma(\Sigma_1 \times \Sigma_2 \times \Sigma_3),$$ which in turn yields $$\sigma((\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2) \times \Sigma_3) \subset \sigma(\Sigma_1 \times \Sigma_2 \times \Sigma_3).$$

Notice we can apply the same reasoning to show that $$\sigma(\Sigma_1 \times (\Sigma_2 \otimes \Sigma_3)) \subset \sigma(\Sigma_1 \times \Sigma_2 \times \Sigma_3).$$

The other inclusion is a lot simpler: $\Sigma_1 \times \Sigma_2 \times \Sigma_3 \subset (\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2) \times \Sigma_3$, so that $$\sigma(\Sigma_1 \times \Sigma_2 \times \Sigma_3) \subset \sigma((\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2) \times \Sigma_3),$$ and similarly
$$\sigma(\Sigma_1 \times \Sigma_2 \times \Sigma_3) \subset \sigma(\Sigma_1 \times (\Sigma_2 \otimes \Sigma_3)).$$

This proves the claim. $\blacksquare$

What happens to the measures was covered by David C. Ullrich in the comments section above.

Comment: Very clear and helpful! Thank you very much! I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad you liked it! :)

Comment: Thank you! I had mistakenly thought that clicking the green button automatically awards the bounty!

Answer (score 8):

I have also thought about the question concerning the associativity of the $\sigma$-algebras and will present another proof, which does not make use of the [$ \pi - \Lambda ~ - $ system Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_system#The_.CF.80-.CE.BB_Theorem) but uses the direct image $ \sigma - $algebra:

---

As mentioned let $ (X_i, M_i, \mu_i) $ for $ i = 1, 2, 3 $ be $\sigma-$finite  measure spaces. Then using the same notation as Giovanni
$$ M_1 \otimes M_2 \otimes M_3 = \sigma \underbrace{\bigl \{ A_1 \times A_2 \times A_3 \bigl | A_i \in M_i \bigr \}}_{= M_1 \times M_2 \times M_3} $$
and
$$ M_1 \otimes ( M_2 \otimes M_3 ) = \sigma  \underbrace{\bigl \{ A \times \Omega \bigl | A \in M_1, \Omega \in M_2 \otimes M_3 \bigr \}}_{=M_1 \times (M_2 \otimes M_3)}. $$

By using the direct image  $\sigma-$algebra we will show that these $\sigma-$algebras are equal:

**First Step:** It is obvious that $ M_1 \times M_2 \times M_3 \subset M_1 \times (M_2 \otimes M_3) $ since every rectangle $ A_2 \times A_3 $, $ A_i \in M_i $ lies in $ M_2 \otimes M_3 $. Hence $ M_1 \otimes M_2 \otimes M_3 \subset M_1 \otimes ( M_2 \otimes M_3) $.

**Second Step:** We now show that also
$ M_1 \otimes (M_2 \otimes M_3) \subset M_1 \otimes M_2 \otimes M_3  $, proving the associativity:

Consider the projection $ \pi: X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3 \to X_2 \times X_3, ~ \pi (x,y,z) = (y,z). $ Then the direct image
$$ \pi_* (M_1 \otimes M_2 \otimes M_3) := \{ \Omega \subseteq X_2 \times X_3 | X_1 \times \Omega = \pi^{-1} (\Omega) \in M_1 \otimes M_2 \otimes M_3 \} $$
is a $ \sigma-$algebra on $ X_2 \times X_3$. (This is a general fact).

***Claim:*** $ M_2 \otimes M_3 \subset \pi_* (M_1 \otimes M_2 \otimes M_3) $.

*Proof of the Claim:* By the minimality of the generated $\sigma-$algebra, it suffices to show that $ M_2 \times M_3 \subset   \pi_* (M_1 \otimes M_2 \otimes M_3) $. So let $ A_2 \times A_3 \in M_2 \times M_3$. But then we have
$$ X_1 \times A_2 \times A_3 \in M_1 \times M_2 \times M_3 $$
by definition, since $ X_1 \in M_1$. (End of the proof of the claim.)

So why does that help?

Again by the minimality of the generated $\sigma-$algebra, what we have to show is that for any $ A \in M_1, ~ \Omega \in M_2 \otimes M_3 $ it holds that
$$ A \times \Omega \in M_1 \otimes M_2 \otimes M_3. $$
But $ A \times \Omega = (A \times (X_2 \times X_3)) \cap (X_1 \times \Omega)$. Obviously $ A \times (X_2 \times X_3 ) \in M_1 \times M_2 \times M_3 $. By the above claim, we also have $ \Omega \in \pi_* (M_1 \otimes M_2 \otimes M_3) $ and therefore $ X_1 \times \Omega \in M_1 \otimes M_2 \otimes M_3$. But since $M_1 \otimes M_2 \otimes M_3$ is a $ \sigma-$algebra, then also the intersection $ (A \times (X_2 \times X_3)) \cap (X_1 \times \Omega) = A \times \Omega \in M_1 \otimes M_2 \otimes M_3$. $ \square$

Comment: Great proof! Ididn't know that sigma algebra was called "direct image", I've always called  it "final sigma algebra (respect to the projection in this case)" by analogy with the final topology