# Associativity of product measure proof check

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

> [Problem:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382169/associativity-of-product-measures?noredirect=1&lq=1) $(X_i, M_i)$ be measurable spaces. Then $M_1 \otimes M_2 \otimes M_3 = M_1 \otimes (M_2 \otimes M_3)$ under the set identification.

I was wondering why none gave the following proof. I believe this would be a neater proof (if correct). I think Timo (linked above) has implicitly assumed the projection map is measurable.

> **Proof:** It suffices to show any measurable set in $M_1 \otimes (M_2 \otimes M_3)$ is measurable in $M_1 \otimes M_2 \otimes M_3$, i.e. 
>   the map 
>   $$ id: (X:=)X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3 \rightarrow X_1 \times (X_2 \times X_3)$$
>   is measurable.
>
> This is measurable, iff it is measurable under composition by $\pi_1:X \rightarrow X_1, \pi_{2,3}:X \rightarrow X_2 \times X_3$ which are measurable iff $\pi_1:X \rightarrow X_1$, $\pi_2: X \rightarrow X_2$ and $\pi_3:X \rightarrow X_3$ are measurable.
>
> This is the exact definition of product measure.

Is this proof right?

Comment: The idea is in my view correct and makes things much more simple. But the proof is incomplete because you only proved one direction. Also the inverse of the map must be shown to be measurable.

Comment: One direction is quite clear as mentioned in the OP, but the other direction has same proof.